# Is the Ubuntu Edge phone going to come out in the United States?

Tags: phone, ubuntu-edge

Is the Ubuntu Edge phone going to come out in the United States? If so, when ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will never come out anywhere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Edge  revealed it fell 64% short of its funding goal, confirmed by http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/08/ubuntu-edge-is-dead-long-live-ubuntu-phones/